# How to know the mime type of the clipboard when pressing the Print-Screen key?

Tags: clipboard, mime-types, mime, printscreen

On Windows, if I press the Print-Screen key, the current screen is captured into the clipboard. Is there a way to check the mime type of the clipboard?

Comment: IIRC it's not just one format, but in there both as DeviceIndependentBitmap and Format17 (which is Device Independent Bitmap v5)

Comment: Confirmed; dumped the clipboard after PrintScreen, the two things in there identified as DeviceIndependentBitmap and Format17. Neither of which are mime types, btw. The Windows clipboard works with string IDs on the clipboard, not mime types.